# Segmentation fault (core dumped), executing a Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt

I was trying to run a program in python that opens a program and read from its stdout. When i run the program code i got a segmentation Fault error, but when i put the code inside the function Myfunc out of the thread it work perfectly! I dont understand what is happening:
Here is my code:

```
class Workspace(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    """ This class is for managing the whole GUI `Workspace'.
        Currently a Workspace is similar to a MainWindow
    """

    def __init__(self):
        #p= subprocess.Popen(["java -Xmx256m -jar bin/HelloWorld.jar"],cwd=r'/home/karen/sphinx4-1.0beta5-src/sphinx4-1.0beta5/', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize= 4024)
        try:
            from Queue import Queue, Empty
        except ImportError:
            while True:
    #from queue import Queue, Empty  # python 3.x
                print "error"

        ON_POSIX = 'posix' in sys.builtin_module_names

        def enqueue_output(out, queue):
            for line in iter(out.readline, b''):
                queue.put(line)
            out.close()

        p= Popen(["java -Xmx256m -jar bin/HelloWorld.jar"],cwd=r'/home/karen/sphinx4-1.0beta5-src/sphinx4-1.0beta5/',stdout=PIPE, shell=True, bufsize= 4024)
        q = Queue()
        t = threading.Thread(target=enqueue_output, args=(p.stdout, q))
        #t = Thread(target=enqueue_output, args=(p.stdout, q))
        t.daemon = True # thread dies with the program
        t.start()

# ... do other things here
        def myfunc(q):
            while True:

                try: line = q.get_nowait()
         # or q.get(timeout=.1)
                except Empty:
                    print('Vacio')
                else: # got line
    # ... do something with line

                    print line  


        thread = threading.Thread(target=myfunc, args=(q,))
        thread.start()
```

The error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: This is a very localized problem, which is not of use to anyone else. Please read [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and then try to debug your code.

Comment: @DavidPärsson: No, it's not very localized. Segmentation faults can occur with any QtGui code related to threads, and not just this specific code.

Comment: Thank you @BrtH! How can i fix it!? Because a need to do it with threads. And exactly! am using a QtGui.

Comment: I'm sorry that I'm not more helpful, but I don't know much about it. What I know is that it's often caused when gui widgets are used within the new thread. What you should do is emit a signal in the myfunc thread and connect that signal in the main code to a function in the main code. Avoid calling gui elements from threads.

Comment: note that qt has the `QThread` class to deal with threading

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have experienced the same problem recently. I have quite a few calls of shell command via subprocess from dependent GUI threads that are working just fine, but one just refuses to work correctly and segfaults. The difference I have came to is exactly in the fact that I'm trying to run it from the main GUI thread and it was segfaulting when i was trying to emit a signal that was usually emitted from subthread!

My solution to avoid segfaulting was to move the part of dialog that required some shell involvement to a separate **QThread**, effectively inheriting the same common class that other threads in my app are using. The problem is gone! **QThread** is the key!

Code schema:

```
class Dialog(QtGui.QDialog):

     def __init__(self):
         ...
         QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.listwidget_a, QtCore.SIGNAL("itemClicked(QListWidgetItem)", self.do_work)
         ...

     def do_work(self, qlistwidgetitem):
         ...
         wc = WorkerClass(str(qlistwidgetitem.text()))
         wc.start()
         wc.wait()
         my_result = wc.getResult()


 class WorkerClass(CommonClass):
     string = ""
     result = ""
     def __init__(string)
         super(WorkerClass, self).__init__()
         self.string = string

     def run():
         self.execute_shell(self.string)
         self.result = self.shell_output

     def get_result(self):
         return self.result

  class CommonClass(QtCore.QThread):

     self.shell_output = ""

     def execute_shell(string):
         ...
         p = Popen(...)
         self.shell_output, self.shell_error = p.communicate()
         self.output_ready.emit(self.shell_output) 
# that last line is where i was segfaulting 
# before I made WorkerClass (my dialog class was 
# inherinting CommonClass directly but it wasn't 
# working in separate thread)
```

I hope that will help!